# CLP: Efficient model of 'not three same values'

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming, eclipse-clp, clp

I need to model this (simple) constraint in Eclipse CLP:

Given three domain variables, lets say `D1`, `D2`, and `D3` and I want to ensure that these three variables will **not** end up with the same value. Two of them can have equal value.

**Version 1**

My first idea was something like:

`D1 #\= D2 or D1 #\= D3`

But I do not like disjunctions in the model.

**Version 2**

Then I changed the model to the form of implications:

`D1 #= D2 => D1 #\= D3`

Is there some more efficient way how to model this constraint?

I was thinking about `alldifferent([D1,D2,D3],2)` or `neg nvalue([D1,D2,D3],1)`
but I am not sure it is not overcomplicated for such a simple usage.

Answer (score 4):

Using `nvalue(N, X)` and then constrain `N` to be larger than 1 (`N #> 1`) will require that there should be 2 or 3 distinct values.

Example:

```
:-lib(ic).
:-lib(ic_search).
:-lib(ic_global).

go :-
    Len = 3,
    dim(X,[Len]),
    X :: 1..Len,
    N :: 1..Len,        

    nvalue(N,X),
    N #> 1,

    term_variables([X],Vars),
    search(Vars,0,first_fail,indomain,complete,[]),

    writeln([n:N, x:X]),
    fail.
```

The model give the following solutions:

```
[n : 2, x : [](1, 1, 2)]
[n : 2, x : [](1, 1, 3)]
[n : 2, x : [](1, 2, 1)]
[n : 2, x : [](1, 2, 2)]
[n : 3, x : [](1, 2, 3)]
[n : 2, x : [](1, 3, 1)]
[n : 3, x : [](1, 3, 2)]
[n : 2, x : [](1, 3, 3)]
[n : 2, x : [](2, 1, 1)]
[n : 2, x : [](2, 1, 2)]
[n : 3, x : [](2, 1, 3)]
[n : 2, x : [](2, 2, 1)]
[n : 2, x : [](2, 2, 3)]
[n : 3, x : [](2, 3, 1)]
[n : 2, x : [](2, 3, 2)]
[n : 2, x : [](2, 3, 3)]
[n : 2, x : [](3, 1, 1)]
[n : 3, x : [](3, 1, 2)]
[n : 2, x : [](3, 1, 3)]
[n : 3, x : [](3, 2, 1)]
[n : 2, x : [](3, 2, 2)]
[n : 2, x : [](3, 2, 3)]
[n : 2, x : [](3, 3, 1)]
[n : 2, x : [](3, 3, 2)]
```

Comment: This works nice! But do you have any performance notes on this solution (eg. in comparison with the other)?

Comment: Not really. It should be faster than your `neg nvalue([D1,D2,D3],1)` and it's more general than the disjunction and implication variants.